# Add a shortcode under variation selectors in Woocommerce single variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I would like to add a shortcode under variation selector and above add to cart button so it would open up a size chart, just like here:

[image]

I got the shortcode, but I don't know what code to use to make it appear in that specific area.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following *(**before** the selected variation price)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'add_shortcode_before_single_variation', 20 );
function add_shortcode_before_single_variation(){
    global $product;

    // HERE comes your shortcode
    echo do_shortcode( "[my_shortcode attr='blabla']" );
}
```

OR this one instead *(**after** the selected variation price)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'add_shortcode_before_single_variation', 15 );
function add_shortcode_before_single_variation(){
    global $product;

    // HERE comes your shortcode
    echo do_shortcode( "[my_shortcode attr='blabla']" );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

it should work *(replacing my fake shortcode with yours)*…